# Minimum residence area for family reunification

Tags: france

I'll be an expat in France, Le Mans. What is the minimum apartment area for a family (4 people) in Le Mans?
And is it necessary to have a separate bed room for the children (4 years and 1 year old)?

(Info required because [the family reunification visa requires "adequately-sized accommodation"](https://france-visas.gouv.fr/en_US/web/france-visas/family-of-foreign-national-residing-in-france), which is locally determined)

Comment: Have you tried contacting the Prefecture in Le Mans and asking them?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure [this page](https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F11166) answers whether you need a separate bedroom for your children, but it does give information on the apartment size.

Open the Conditions section. It contains the income and housing requirements.

Based on [this page](http://www.cohesion-territoires.gouv.fr/les-zonages-des-politiques-du-logement?id_courant=2094) it looks like La Mans falls into zone B2. B2 requires 24 square meters for 2 people plus 10 square meters per additional person up to 8 people. If your family size is four, your living space must be 44 square meters.